# Static linking libc++ with clang on OSX

Tags: macos, build, clang, static-libraries, libc++

I am trying to statically link libc++ on OSX 10.9 64 bit

Here's what I did :

1) Build a libc++64.a with fPIC added by modifying the script "buildit" which comes with the libc++ source.

2) Building all my own sources with fPIC and adding my own include path to the new libc++ source include directory, also using -nostdinc++ as compile flag.

3) Linking with "../build/libc++64.a"

I am sure it picks up the static lib, but it still gives me an error :

```
ld: illegal text-relocation to '__ZTVSt9bad_alloc' in /usr/lib/libc++.dylib from '__ZN3slm15ReadProblemFileERNS_5ModelERNS_3LogEPKwb' in bin/clang-darwin-4.2.1/release/address-model-64/threading-multi/read.o for architecture x86_64
```

What I don't understand is why and how it still locate and use `/usr/lib/libc++.dylib`

UPDATE :

When I do the same cross building for 32 bit on the same machine, the build succeed, but I still get a dependency on libc++.dylib output from otool -L :

```
bin/clang-darwin-4.2.1/release/address-model-32/threading-multi/libsulum20.dynlib:  libsulum20.dynlib (compatibility version 0.0.0, current version 0.0.0)  /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1197.1.1)  /usr/lib/libc++.1.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 120.0.0)
```

Comment: Have you linked libc++abi, and have you tried linking with `clang` instead of `clang++`?

Comment: @rubenvb Thanks for the reply. If I use clang instead of clang++, then  it spits out missing symbols from std like :Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "std::bad_typeid::what() const"

Comment: What concerns me is that I can find no relevant information about linking static with libc++, nor do apple provide a static build by default, which is making me think no one really do this.

Comment: Indeed, no one really does this. Why do you think you need to link to it statically? Also: when linking with `clang`, you'll need to add `-lc++` (or in your case it may be better to use `../build/libc++64.a`), and libc++abi to your command.

Comment: @rubenvb, in my case I want to link statically to `libc++` because I am going to deploy the library in a `heroku cedar` machine, where `libc++` is not available.

Comment: @BoJensen, I am interested in solving this. How have you modified the `buildit` script to create `libc++64.a`? Do you have those modifications handy?